# Migrating issue of drupal website

Tags: drupal, server

I have developed a site using drupal. Now I moved from test server to live server. Now if I make changes to the test site its reflecting to live site too. I am surprised. Please could anyone tell that how should I fix above problem.

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/node/776864 read this

Answer (score 1):

Ok, assuming you mean changes at the content level (like content types, menus, taxonomies, users, ..), then it probably means you're sharing the database between the two sites. You'll need to point the one of them to a copy of that database so you split the sites. This can be done by adjusting the sites/default/settings.php file typically.